# How to handle 4000 sip users and 10000 calls with same ip?

Tags: cluster-computing, asterisk, voip, kamailio

which technology I should use to handle 4000 sip users and 10000 calls with same ip with billing? I want it to configure so that all the sip users will use same ip and with proper billing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi load is not something that can be easy setuped by reading one page of answer, or even any single book.

It require years of experience to understand issues that can arise.

From opensource stack can be used opensips/kamailio and cluster of some of opensource billing or 2600hz platform or custom billing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle such a load you should use Kamailio + a cluster of RTPProxy servers. The following repository contains a set of Ansible playbooks for deploying an Active-Passive Kamailio cluster with a cluster of load-balanced RTPProxy servers. I think it is a good point to start:

https://github.com/ghrst/Kamailio-HA